# Multiple values for one column on a single list item

Tags: list, custom-list

I'm relatively new to SharePoint and have been trying to figure out if the following is something that a SharePoint list is capable of capturing: 
[image]

Is it possible to have, for example, a single list item, and then have multiple values in a column that map to values in other columns? So Goal1 is linked to Action1 which is linked to Date1 and then users can add Goal2, Action2, Date2? There would be a max of 3 goals, and the entering of Action and Date information is required IF the Goal field is filled (but the Goal field is not Required). I'm thinking this has something to do with dependent lists?

I know I can probably just create an editable Excel on the SharePoint, but I think a list might be better. Would appreciate any ideas you have!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure you will have 3 goals always, you can create columns G1 A1 D1, G2 A2 D2,...D3 for Goal, Action and Date so that you have all information in single item

OR

use a single list and group your records (this can be done from list settings) by **Title** and **Name** . This will create 3 items though

I am adding image to give you an idea of how it looks, here the items are grouped by project name(title column)

[image: group by]